# Why is C++ so popular for Image Processing?

Tags: image-processing, c++

I have been a student of Image Processing for 3 years now and have been using C++ as the programming language to implement different Image processing operations. But I don't really why in particular C++ is so popular for Image processing rather than other languages like Java and C-sharp.

Could you please explain why C++ is so popular for image processing?

Thanks!

Comment: Simply because it is very fast, compared to the languages you mentioned. It is also reasonably easy to program with (i.e. OOP). Last but not least, it is old and many libraries exists in C++, which are reliable and efficient. Coding in C++ is the best way to utilize them.

Answer (score 1):

At the "dawn" of modern image processing/computer vision, C++ had the best combination of speed and industry support (meaning tools, libraries, etc and infrastructure to support them).

OpenCV is natively written in C++, look at the [OpenCV about page](http://opencv.org/about.html), and you can quickly get a sense for these historical currents.